# I trying to pritn with print commamd but ir doesnr work

Tags: python, command, syntax-error

i got pyton and lesrning programation but i cannot do homewrok print command my teacher gived me homework is try to printing youre name but i cant its not workign on pyton i tryied the print comand and it dont do it gived me eror it says sintax error i cant print on pyton

i tri doinf print command on pyton window it dont work it gived me eror it says syntax Error i cant print on piton it said sintax error i wrote print(peter songo why ks it not working i wantign know why it not wokring

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your string in parentheses.

```py
print("Peter Songo")
```

Comment: waht is strign.

Comment: @PeterE.N.I.Songo  Is this satire?

Comment: waht is satire?

Comment: ssory i amnew to programing